terraform .tfstate file doesn't change after removing itens
For some unknown reason, the removed items remain in the state file after I remove from the .tfstate file.
CASE:

downloaded my state file(my_statefile.tfstate) from cloud_bucket where it's stored
In the application cloned repo, I placed the file in the folder that contains the items I want to remove from the state
ran terraform init
ran terraform state list -state=my_statefile.tfstate

output:
item 1
item 2
item 3


ran terraform state rm -state=my_statefile.tfstate item1
ran terraform state list -state=my_statefile.tfstate

output:
item 2
item 3

However when I inspect the file with cat my_statefile.tfstate
the item 1 is still there..
I even created a empty file called empty.tfstate and tried the flow described above and got the same results which is kind of odd.
Does anyone have any clues on what can be happening here?

Presumably because you are still interacting with the remote state, the local file simply does not matter and is entirely ignored.

good point it can be true, so why the remote state file in the cloud_bucket is also not getting changed? what would trigger that change

Evidently the state is changed based on the changed state list output. Wherever that state is stored it got updated. If the file in the bucket is not changing then it is not the actual state file, simple as that.
